# How do I filter and count objects in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to implement the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on an array in which every element is an object like this:

```
{
  "start": 1234,
  "end": 4321,
  "count": 0
}
```

I want to remove duplicates from my array while incrementing the `count` property.

At the moment I only managed to filter the array by the `start` property using this code:

```
 var temp = {};
 myArray = myArray.filter(function(obj) {
     if (obj.start in temp) {
         return false;
     } else {
         temp[obj.start] = true;
         return true;
     }
 });
```

What I want to achieve is a filter that works on these conditions (for better explaining, I will refer to elements in `temp` as `tempObj` and the current object as `obj`):

> - if `obj.start` === `tempObj.start` && `obj.end` === `tempObj.end`, `obj.count` += 1
> - if `obj.start` === `tempObj.start` || `obj.end` === `tempObj.end`, `obj.count` = `tempObj.count` + 1
> - if `obj.start` > `tempObj.start` && `obj.end` < `tempObj.end`, `obj.count` = `tempObj.count` + 1
> - else add a new element to `temp` with `count` = 1

Is it possible using the filter method? If not, what is the correct way? I would rather not use any framework.

EDIT: as per RobG request, to make the question more clear I'm adding an input and output example.

**Example input:**

```
myArray = [{
  "start": 1105,
  "end": 1501,
  "count": 0
},

{
  "start": 1105,
  "end": 1003,
  "count": 0
},

{
  "start": 1110,
  "end": 1120,
  "count": 0
},

{
  "start": 1105,
  "end": 1003,
  "count": 0
},

{
  "start": 1115,
  "end": 1120,
  "count": 0
}]
```

**Desired output:**

```
myArray = [{
  "start": 1105,
  "end": 1501,
  "count": 1
},

{
  "start": 1105,
  "end": 1003,
  "count": 3
},

{
  "start": 1110,
  "end": 1120,
  "count": 1
}

{
  "start": 1115,
  "end": 1120,
  "count": 1
}]
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear (to me). Can you provide sample input and output? You want to remove "duplicates" (without saying what defines a duplicate), but *filter* creates a new array, it doesn't modify the array being filtered.

Comment: @RobG a duplicate is an object with the same start and end as one or more objects in the array. I'll provide the info requested ASAP

Comment: Since your result is different to the input, I'd suggest using *reduce* and build the new array as you go, adding new elements and updating existing along the way. You could also use *forEach*, but *reduce* is more semantic.

Comment: @RobG I'll try that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
myArray = [{
    "start": 1105,
    "end": 1501,
    "count": 0
  },

  {
    "start": 1105,
    "end": 1003,
    "count": 0
  },

  {
    "start": 1110,
    "end": 1120,
    "count": 0
  },

  {
    "start": 1105,
    "end": 1003,
    "count": 0
  },

  {
    "start": 1115,
    "end": 1120,
    "count": 0
  }
]





var obj = {};

for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
  obj[myArray[i]['start']] = myArray[i];
}

myArray = new Array();
var count = 0;
for (var key in obj) {
  obj[key].count = count++;
  myArray.push(obj[key]);
}



console.log(myArray)
```

updated answer.

```js
myArray = [{
    "start": 1105,
    "end": 1501,
    "count": 0
  },

  {
    "start": 1105,
    "end": 1003,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "start": 1105,
    "end": 1003,
    "count": 0
  },

  {
    "start": 1110,
    "end": 1120,
    "count": 0
  },

  {
    "start": 1105,
    "end": 1003,
    "count": 0
  },

  {
    "start": 1115,
    "end": 1120,
    "count": 0
  }
]


function removeDoopCount(myArray) {
  const start = x => myArray[x].start;
  const end = x => myArray[x].end;
  let hash = new Map();
  for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    let key = start(i) + ':' + end(i);
    let item = myArray[i];
    let values = hash.get(key);
    if (values) values.push(item);
    else hash.set(key, [item]);
  }
  let ar = [];
  hash.forEach((v, k, m) => (count = 1, v.forEach(i => i.count += count++), ar.push(v[v.length - 1])));
  return ar;
}
console.log(removeDoopCount(myArray));
```

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way to check the conditions on both start and end properties and, if met, increase the count.

Comment: @elegali also your Desired output for {
  "start": 1115,
  "end": 1120,
  "count": 2
} is wrong, it should only be count 1

Comment: thank you very much for the update! It's what I was looking for! I've tried it and it returns an array of arrays with just one object inside, is it possible to turn it into an array of objects? In the meantime, I'm accepting your answer :) Ah, yeah, you're right, I've mady a typo while writing the example, thank you for pointing it out!